# git: post-update checkout not working

Tags: git, post-update

I am trying to set git up with http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/#website to manage my site. I am working using the git gui in win7

I have gotten to the last step in the instructions:  git push website

After pushing to the website, I was able to confirm that the object directory in ~/website.git is updated.

my hook is called 'post_update' it has the following contents

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "**** Pushing data to Live Server.">>~/hi.txt
echo
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/***/public_html/b1a git checkout -f
```

when I go to /public_html/b1a, it is an empty directory. also I have changed the hooks directory and b1a to 777. after a push to the website remote I can see that hi.txt has been created, so I assume that the hook is working but that the line

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/***/public_html/b1a git checkout -f
```

is not. how can I fix this

I would appreciate any help,

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: I think you are supposed to replace the `***` with a real path

Comment: it is the full path, I just changed it to *** here for security purposes

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. the hook had been trying to send to the 'b1a' directory which is NOT a git directory in my setup( neither bare nor normal ). I think this is obvious ( in retrospect but I didn't think of it ) - Regards, Bill